# gap.plot (x axis broken): how to add error bars with arrows()? Is it possible?

Tags: r

I would like to use arrows() and add the error bars on a figure created with gap.plot. This works fine but only for the data until the axis break. How to add the missing error bars for the data after the axis break?
[Missing error bars after the axis break](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3I53.png)

My code:

```
     library(plotrix)
     par(bty="n") # deleting the box
     ymin <- 0.25
     ymax <- 1
     with(subset(mydata, mechanism=='Facilitation'), 
          gap.plot(day,mean, gap=c(51,116), gap.axis="Time (day)", 
                   xlab="Time (days)", ylab="(mm)",pch=16,
                   col="#D55E00",xtics=c(1,50,119,133), ytics=c(0.25,0.5,0.75,1), ylim=c(ymin, ymax)))
     with(subset(mydata, mechanism=='Inhibition'),
          gap.plot(day,mean, gap=c(51,116), gap.axis="Time (day)", 
                   xlab="Time (days)", ylab="(mm)",pch=16,
                   col="#0072B2", ytics=c(0.25,0.5,0.75,1), ylim=c(ymin, ymax), add=TRUE))
     abline(v=seq(from=50.5,to=53.5,by=.001), col="white")  # hiding vertical lines

     ## error bars
     with(subset(mydata, mechanism=='Facilitation'), arrows(day, mean-se, day, mean+se, length=0.05, angle=90, code=3))
     with(subset(mydata, mechanism=='Inhibition'), arrows(day, mean-se, day, mean+se, length=0.05, angle=90, code=3))
```

My data is here with calculated standard error values (se) that I am trying to add to the figure:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/aglp4sy56bx56rp/mydata.csv?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone helped me to solve this problem so I am sharing the answer.

[Gap.plot adds error bars at the wrong location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1aX4.jpg)

The 'day' values have to be adjusted and then based on these new values the error bars can be plotted for the higher and lower data points separately.

```
  #create new column in data that has adjusted day values
mydata$adjusted_day = mydata$day - 65

## error bars for lower day data points
with(subset(mydata, mechanism=='Facilitation'), arrows(day, mean-se, day,mean+se, length=0.05, angle=90, code=3))
with(subset(mydata, mechanism=='Inhibitionn'), arrows(day, mean-se, day, mean+se, length=0.05, angle=90, code=3))

##error bars for higher day data points

with(subset(mydata, mechanism=='Facilitation'), arrows(adjusted_day, mean-se, adjusted_day, mean+se, length=0.05, angle=90, code=3))
with(subset(mydata, mechanism=='Inhibition'), arrows(adjusted_day, mean-se, adjusted_day, mean+se, length=0.05, angle=90, code=3))
```